# Sublime Text 3 - how to remove red background

Tags: sublimetext3

How to remove that Red background in Sublime. There is some slash in that line "/" when I remove that slash red background disappears. But how do I remove that red background permanently

[image]

Comment: `preferences -> color scheme`

Comment: Red lines comes when there is error in the code .Your syntax might be incorrect .. try to remove URL attribute

Comment: No, this is not an error I am using ES6 syntax. So how to disable that error background permanently.

Answer (score 0):

just providing more information on this in case someone else looks into this. As mention above, you would need to edit the XML file associated to the color scheme you're using. If you're using a theme from package control you most likely would need to utilize PackageResourceViewer to open the XML file.

Once you've located the file, you would simply need to comment out the background values for the Invalid key.

For example refer to the snippet below:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Invalid</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>invalid</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <!--key>background</key-->
            <!--string>#ec5f67</string-->
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#ffffff</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This way you can maintain the syntax colors and suppress the annoying red highlight/background when there is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Where is this XML located ?